# nginx and docker: route all requests from each service properly

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-location

I have several services running in docker (using docker-compose), each in its own container.

I am using nginx as the proxy server.

partial `nginx.conf`:

```
upstream a_servers {
    server a:8080;
}

upstream b_servers {
    server b:8080;
}
server {
    location / {

        proxy_pass         http://a_servers/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

    location /b {

        proxy_pass         http://b_servers;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Problem:

These two services both need to load their own `/js/build.js` file.  However, when service `b` makes a request for `/js/build.js`, nginx routes it to the first option and makes a request for the build.js from service `a` instead.

Is there a way to prepend `/b` to all requests coming from service `b`?  Also, what is the name for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Try: `proxy_redirect   default;` in `/b` section

Comment: `service a` still receives the request instead of `service a`

Comment: You can try using the sub filter module to modify the response body and pretend the /b that way. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html